# Environment requirement in training image dataset for classifier

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, data-sets, classification

I have a question about preparing the dataset of positive samples for a cascaded classifier that will be used for object detection.

As positive samples, I have been given 3 sets of images:

1. a set of **colored** images in full size (about 1200x600) with a **white background** and with the object displayed at a different angles in each image
2. another set with the same images in grayscale and with a **white background**, scaled down to the detection window size (60x60)
3. another set with the same images in grayscale and with a **black background**, scaled down to the detection window size (60x60)

My question is that in Set 1, should the background really be white? Should it not instead be an **environment** that the object is likely to be found in in the testing dataset? Or should I have a fourth set where the images are in their natural environments? How does environment figure into the training samples?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should have a fourth dataset where the images are in their natural environments because you will need information with white background when you will be testing the datasets.

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about using OpenCV. I've realized I actually don't need full size images either, do I? All images will be resized anyway by the classification trainer down to detection window size, i.e. 60x60.

Comment: What kind of object are you working with?